# PrimeFaces: how can I check a p:column with selectionMode="multiple"?

Tags: checkbox, primefaces, datatable

I have a `<p:dataTable>` with a `<p:column selectionMode="multiple" />`. When I have a **single row** displayed in the dataTable, I want my application to **automatically check this row** (and also the "checkAll" checkbox displayed on the table header).

I've done this via JavaScript and it visually worked. However, when submitting the form, it seems the "checked" value isn't submitted. If I click on the checkbox twice (to uncheck and check it again), it works.

**JSF:**

```
<p:dataTable var="invoiceGroup"
             selection="#{chargeBean.selectedInvoiceGroupBeans}"
             value="#{chargeBean.invoiceGroupList}"
             rowKey="#{invoiceGroup.id}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
    ...
</p:dataTable>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
function selectTableElements() {
    var checkBoxes = $('#invoiceGroupTable td.ui-selection-column input[type="checkbox"]');
    var paginatorPages = $('#invoiceGroupTable .ui-paginator .ui-paginator-pages .ui-paginator-page'); 
    if (checkBoxes.length === 1 && paginatorPages.length === 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $('#invoiceGroupTable th input[type="checkbox"]').click();
        }, 10);
    }
}
```

Is there a way of doing this server-side?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would prefer a multiple selection dataTable `without checkboxes`(multiple select just with `CTRL` key http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableRowSelectionMultiple.jsf ).

Secondly, I don't know why you don't check(in server side) if the list(`invoiceGroupList`) has only a member/object and add it automatically to the second list, the `selectedInvoiceGroupBeans`. If you still want this to be also visually, you can keep your javascript/jquery function that already does it's job. Also you can take a look at the `Primefaces RequestContext` component: you can call javascript functions from server side, if you want some more interesting visual design, for example that row to be selected or even highlighted after running the action method - http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf.

Thirdly, why are you using a `setTimeout` javascript function? If you push a `commandButton` that does the submit and on click calls your javascript function, the button will first do the submit and then your checkbox select and by doing that you won't get the expected behavior.

Comment: 1. It's part of our product visual identity, we must have checkboxes for multiple selections.   

2. By now, I made this check, and changed the javascript to disable the checkbox (besides checking it) if there's only one element.   

3. It's because this is called at the same time the table is rendered. If I don't put the setTimeout, Internet Explorer won't let the table render and will execute the `.click` on the not-rendered element.

Comment: @otuka I'm glad everything is OK now!